# Running Queries in Parallel

Tags: mysql

I have a list of queries that I use to warmup my InnoDB database tables.  Currently, I run these queries sequentially and they take some time to run.  I was wondering if there was a way I could run them in parallel to speed up the time it takes to run all the queries?

Comment: InnoDB is not like an internal combustion engine. It doesn't need warming up. Perhaps you might like to rephrase the question so that it makes sense.

Comment: Caches are part of high performance systems, and their performance is described by temperature. Even if InnoDB somehow doesnt have any caching, the OS does, so it's not a terrible thought.

Comment: Maybe I should have used the term "preload" instead of "warmup."  I didn't come up with this concept myself: see http://goo.gl/4z6mj and http://goo.gl/UC2o0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply open multiple connections to the database server from the same host or from several hosts. Then, you can split the **INDEPENDENT** queries over the established connections.

The InnoDB engine will take care of the required locking. As you may know, InnoDB engine supports row-level locking which will speedup the queries (compared to MyISAM) when there is a high contention (concurrent update/select queries).

Comment: how would I go about opening multiple connections via an SSH terminal?

Comment: You can create a small PHP/perl script to execute a subset of the queries. Then, execute the script in background and run it again  with the next subset of queries and so on.

Comment: If you don't like/know scripting, you can using `mysql -uroot -pPassword DB_NAME < SQL_file1 &` to execute the 1st subset. Then, move on to the 2nd file and so on.